# what is the covariance between $\hat Y$ and$\hat \beta_1$?

Tags: statistics, regression, estimation, covariance

I'm having a crisis of faith here, I'm trying to prove that $\beta_0$is unbiased.

The formula for $\beta_0$(the parameter) is:
$$\beta_0=\mu_Y-\beta_1\mu_X$$
The formula for $\hat \beta_0$(the estimator) is:
$$\hat \beta_0=\hat Y-\hat \beta_1 X$$

Which can be rewritten as:

$$\hat \beta_0=\bar Y-\beta_1\bar X$$

Thus:
$$E(\hat \beta_0)=E(\bar Y)-E(\hat \beta_1\bar X)$$
$$=\mu_Y-E(\hat \beta_1\bar X)$$
$$=\beta_0+\beta_1\mu_X-E(\hat \beta_1 \bar X)$$

Now, it's easy to see that if: 
$$cov(\hat \beta_1, \bar X)=0$$ 
then: 
$$E(\hat \beta_1\bar X)=E(\hat \beta_1)E(\bar X)$$
$$=E(\hat \beta_1)\mu_X$$ 
Thus:

$$E(\hat \beta_0)=\beta_0+\beta_1\mu_X-E(\hat \beta_1) \mu_X$$

and given that $E(\hat \beta_1)=\beta_1$ (which I know how to prove):

$$E(\hat \beta_0)=\beta_0$$

Yet how can $cov(\hat \beta_1, \bar X)$ be equal to zero? $\hat \beta_1$ changes when $\bar X$ changes, these terms must be related by definition?

Comment: I think I do not understand the problem. If $\hat{\beta}_0=\hat{Y}-\beta_1\hat{X}$, then taking expectations we get $E(\hat{\beta}_0)=E(\hat{Y})-\beta_1E(\hat{X})$.

Comment: That kinda makes sense...my head is mush right now (making derivations for 5+ hours) so will look back tomorrow ^^

Comment: By using $E(\hat Y)$ and $E(\hat X)$ we won't prove that $\hat \beta_0$ is unbiased I think. We'll just end up with $E(\hat \beta_0)=E(\hat \beta_0)$, with doesn't really prove anything ....

Answer (score 1):

I think if you consider about the estimator, say $\hat{\beta_1}$, $\bar{x}$ is no long a random variable but the specific given data, s.t.
$$ \mathbb{E}[\hat{\beta_1} \bar{x}] = \bar{x}~ \mathbb{E}[\hat{\beta_1}] = \bar{x} ~ \beta_1$$.

Comment: well yes, I think this would be the case, if we limit ourselves to one data set.

But in every given data set, $\hat \beta_0$, $\hat \beta_1$, $\bar X$ and $\bar y$ will change, correct?

We are trying to determine the most likely (expected) value of  $\hat \beta_0$, taken from one of many possible datasets.

If we say that $\bar X$ is a constant, don't we also say that $\bar X$ is the same, regardless of dataset?

This seems contraintuitive to me ^^

Comment: @Magnus Intuitively, I think the main propose for regression model is that predict $y_{i}$ by given data $x_{i}$. Mathematically, when we min the expectation of predict error, this expectation seems should be conditional expectation w.r.t. $X$. see the second answer in this [question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71863/problem-with-proof-of-conditional-expectation-as-best-predictor).